# What happens after head becomes 0 in recurrsive call?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

```
void fun1(struct Node* head)
{
 if(head == NULL)
    return;

 fun1(head->next);
  printf("%d  ", head->data);
}
```

after head->next becomes 0, how it is printed backward, please explain the flow ?

Comment: It returns to the point after the function call and your recursive call is *before* the `printf()`? What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Have you search how recursive work ?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Simulate in on paper. That's a very good exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to think of the calls in terms of how they operate, with a call stack.

The function hits the `fun1` call before it prints anything, so it will go all the way to the base case before printing. Then it prints as it works its way out of each call; printing the list backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the code something like "print the next node if there is one, then print this one". The operation to print the next node prints the one after that first, until the end of the list.